# Swift - Local Image Manipulation Without Cache

Tags: ios, swift, image, caching

**Goal**

Manipulate several high-resolution local images without catching them, then select and display some of them in a collection view.

**Limitations**

[PHImageManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phimagemanager#overview) does not have an option to retrieve a local image without catching it. PHAsset does not have a property to specify its local path. Finally, it is not possible for me to use an array of UIImage or NSData objects because it reaches the memory limit quickly and crashes.

**Tools**

Xcode 8.1 - Swift 3.0.1

**Current Situation**

First, I fetch the assets and then iterate through them to get their local path. The reason for getting their local path is to access them without catching them using `UIImage(contentsOfFile: localPath)` or `UIImage.init(data: Data(contentsOf: localPath))`. Then, I run some business logic over the images and I select some of them. Finally, I store the local path of the selected images in an array, to be then used by the collection view.

*Note*: In iOS 10 or later, the `requestContentEditingInput` [completion handler](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phasset/1624061-requestcontenteditinginput#parameters) is call on the main queue.

**Problem**

Everything works until the point where the collection view tries to load the local image. The image’s local path is successfully loaded using `UIImage(contentsOfFile: localPath)` inside the `requestContentEditingInput` completion handler. However, the same image’s local path when is loaded using the same function inside the collection view function `collectionView(_ collectionView:, cellForItemAt indexPath:)` it brings `nil`.

Therefore, I wonder what I am missing or doing wrong. I already tried to use the asset `cancelContentEditingInputRequest` thinking that maybe there was a type of lock on the image, but it did not fix the issue.

**Code Sample**

```
var imagesSelected = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var imageCollectionView: UICollectionView!

private func processImages() {
  ...
  assets.enumerateObjects({ (asset, count, stop) in 
    ...
    asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions(), completionHandler: { (input, _) in
      if let url = input?.fullSizeImageURL {
        if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.relativePath) {
          ...
          if (...) {
            self. imagesSelected.append(url.relativePath)
            self.imageCollectionView.reloadData()
          }
        }
      }
    })
  })
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

  cell.productImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.images[indexPath.row])

  return cell;
}
```